# Handle threads on Android UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler

In my application I want to check the network status on device,If no network connectivity is detected on device the i want to show a toast saying no network connection and then exit the application.And if the connection is detected on device then i have to load a list from webservice and display it on screen

I have done following code in onCreate function of application.It is running on emulator but not on real device.The reason for this to showANR on device is i am trying to handle so many threads on UI which is not appreciated in android.Please guide me how to do this using AsyncTask.

any code snippet or link to tutorial or suggestions will be helpful to me

```
boolean connected = false;
            ConnectivityManager connectivitymanager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkinfo = connectivitymanager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            connected = networkinfo != null && networkinfo.isAvailable()
                    && networkinfo.isConnected();
            Log.v("Message ", connected + "");
            Log.v("Message ", networkinfo.getReason());
            //Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, connected + "", 2000).show();
            //connected = false;
            Log.v("Message 1", connected + "");
            if (connected == false) {
                CategoryActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Log.v("Message ", connected + "");
                        Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this,
                                "No Internet Connection detected on device", 3000).show();
                    }
                });
                Handler handler1 = new Handler();
                handler1.postDelayed(new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }), 4000);
            } else {
                CategoryArray = new JSONArray();
                final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(
                        CategoryActivity.this, "", "Loading...", false, true);
                pd.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            sleep(5000);
                            // Log.v("TAG","in try block");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                        }
                        pd.dismiss();
                        // Log.v("TAG","progress dismiss");
                    }
                }.start();

                handler.postDelayed(new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        CategoryArray = CW
                                .getCategory("http://www.balajeebazaar.com/RestServiceImpl.svc/categorydetails");
                        // TODO: handle exception

                        for (int i = 0; i <= CategoryArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                            try {
                                String[] val = new String[3];
                                Log.v("category array : ",
                                        CategoryArray.getString(i));
                                val = CategoryArray.getString(i).split(",");
                                CategoryID.add(i, val[0]);
                                CategoryList.add(i, val[1]);
                                val = null;
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        adapter = new CategoryListAdapter(CategoryActivity.this,
                                CategoryList);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }), 5000);
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:234)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:258)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:122)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486):     at com.ecommerce.balajeebazaar.CategoryActivity$Loader.doInBackground(CategoryActivity.java:181)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486):     at com.ecommerce.balajeebazaar.CategoryActivity$Loader.doInBackground(CategoryActivity.java:1)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-18 18:30:07.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486): 
                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:256)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5486):     4 more
```

Comment: yes it works fine **on device too when it is connected to net**..but when i try to run the application by turning the device to airplane mode ,then instead of showing up the toast it shows force close

Comment: might be getting exception  null pointer exception ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read up on the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) yourself before applying the solution I have posted below, in order to better understand what is going on.

This is what you need in your `Activity` (it must replace all the code you posted):

```
    boolean connected = false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivitymanager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkinfo = connectivitymanager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    connected = networkinfo != null && networkinfo.isAvailable()
            && networkinfo.isConnected();
    Log.v("Message ", connected + "");
    Log.v("Message ", networkinfo.getReason());
    //Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, connected + "", 2000).show();
    //connected = false;
    Log.v("Message 1", connected + "");
    if (connected == false) {
      Toast.makeText(CategoryActivity.this, "No Internet Connection detected on device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
      finish();
    } else {
      new Loader().execute();
    }
```

This is the `AsyncTask` which should be an inner class of your `Activity`:

```
    private class Loader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
      final ProgressDialog pd;

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show( CategoryActivity.this, "", "Loading...", false, true);
        pd.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
        super.onPreExecute();
      }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground( Void... arg0 ) {
        CategoryArray = new JSONArray();
        CategoryArray = CW.getCategory("http://www.balajeebazaar.com/RestServiceImpl.svc/categorydetails");

        for (int i = 0; i <= CategoryArray.length() - 1; i++) {
          try {
              String[] val = new String[3];
              Log.v("category array : ", CategoryArray.getString(i));
              val = CategoryArray.getString(i).split(",");
              CategoryID.add(i, val[0]);
              CategoryList.add(i, val[1]);
              val = null;
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

        adapter = new CategoryListAdapter(CategoryActivity.this, CategoryList);

        return null;
      }


      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute( Void result ) {
        pd.dismiss();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        super.onPostExecute( result );
      }
    }
```

**Note**

I wasn't able to check if the above actually works - but it should put you on the right track.

Comment: wow nice solution..I will try this and let you know .Thanks for replying

Comment: i implemented this code segment and got the error please see the logcat output i have posted as edit

Comment: What's on line 181 in CategoryActivity?

Comment: `CategoryList.add(i, val[1]);` this is there on 181 line

Comment: It would appear that the problem is tied to your array `val` - Are you sure the data is read correctly from the JSONArray?

Comment: yes I am getting data from json .The json array length is 13 wat i am getting from server before getting that logcat trace i get `verbose on logcat as VERBOSE/response code(486): 200
VERBOSE/results length :(486): 13
VERBOSE/category array :(486): 53•Books•`

Answer (score 0):

A nice [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) on AsyncTasks and Handlers.

In really short, the idea of AsyncTask - you make a private class which extends AsyncTask in your Activity. 
Doing this, you automatically get access to this Activities UI Thread from the AsyncTask class.

In AsyncTaks there are a couple of methods you should pay attention to. They are explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

What you should know is that only doInBackground() is executed in a separate Thread. Everything else is invoked on the UI thread of the Activity, where your AsyncTask is defined.

Simple scenario:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     // stuff
   new MyAsyncTask().execute(); //this should be invoked only once
   }

   private class MyAsyncTask() extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, <TypeOfResult Or Void>> {

    @Override //executed on the UI thread of MyActivity
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
                   //prepare some stuff
            }

    @Override //executed in a separate Thread. This thread is automatically handled by AsyncTask
    protected <TypeOfResult or Void> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //long operation
    }

            @Override //executed on the UI thread of MyActivity
    protected void onPostExecute(<TypeOf Result Or Void>) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        // do stuff with result from long operation
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying with a nice tutorial link I will try this too

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need an AsyncTask, you can use regular Java threading to accomplish what you need (far easier for a background task like this).